# Capture and evaluate function arguments within function body

Tags: r, function

I would like to capture a function's arguments within its body to help with logging. I have found that `match.call()` and `sys.call()` work when the argument value is explicitly stated in the function call, but don't output an evaluated value when an object name is used.

Here's a simplified example:

```
gauss_vector <- function(number) {
  sys_args <- as.list(sys.call())
  match_args <- as.list(match.call())
  output <- rnorm(n = number)
  list(sys_args,
       match_args,
       output)
}
```

When this function is called like this:

```
gauss_vector(number = 5)
```

The resulting list includes the value `5`.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
gauss_vector

[[1]]$number
[1] 5


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
gauss_vector

[[2]]$number
[1] 5


[[3]]
[1]  0.9663434  0.8051087  0.1576298  0.3189806 -2.3110680
```

However, when the function is called like this:

```
n <- 5
gauss_vector(number = n)
```

The resulting list only includes `n`.

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
gauss_vector

[[1]]$number
n


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
gauss_vector

[[2]]$number
n


[[3]]
[1] -0.6017670 -0.7631405  0.7793892 -0.7529637  1.3022802
```

Is there a way to capture the evaluated figure rather than the object name when the function is called in the second way?

Comment: I think you need `eval` or `eval.parent` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `eval` all the arguments passed to the function.

```
gauss_vector <- function(number) {

   sys_args <- as.list(sys.call())
   sys_args[-1] <- lapply(sys_args[-1], eval)
   match_args <- as.list(match.call())
   match_args[-1] <- lapply(match_args[-1], eval)
   output <- rnorm(n = number)
   list(sys_args,match_args,output)
}

gauss_vector(n)
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#gauss_vector

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 5


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#gauss_vector

#[[2]]$number
#[1] 5


#[[3]]
#[1]  0.6998265  0.4037748  1.8558809 -0.1343624 -1.5600925
```

Comment: @Ronak_Shah - that's great. Is there a way to retain the list name to make it easier to refer back to each specific argument?

Comment: It returns expected result if you pass it as named argument i.e `gauss_vector(number = n)`

Comment: I think @JayAchar wants the last line of the function to be: `list(sys_args=sys_args, match_args=match_args, output=output)`

Comment: I wanted to access the eval(argument) by name rather than position in case the user enters arguments in a different order. Obviously not relevent to this simplified example. Thanks both - will accept.